# Object Oriented Metrics?

Tags: oop, object

Folks,

Does anyone have a good understanding of Object Oriented Metrics; I am looking for some guidance on where can I start.

I found the below resource:
http://yunus.hacettepe.edu.tr/~sencer/oom.html

Thanks,
Amit

Answer (score 1):

If you have academic interests, Chidamber and Kemerer's paper of 1994 is the classic reference.

Answer (score 0):

Reading Chidamber & Kemerer research paper will help you in learning in depth, if you have academic interests as stated in above answer. Here, the link
of public Revised paper December 1993: [OOMetrics](https://www.eso.org/%7Etcsmgr/oowg-forum/TechMeetings/Articles/OOMetrics.pdf)